# Chamar lista em função no python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou criando um script para meu curso de python.

O script recebe como entrada uma sequência de números inteiros terminada por zero e me devolve os números em ordem crescente, removendo os repetidos.

O script funcionou de primeira compilação, mas agora que o dividi em uma função ele está dando algum erro com a 'lista' que não entendo:

> TypeError: remove_repetidos() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lista'

Segue meu script:

```
def remove_repetidos (lista):
    lista2 = set(lista)
    lista = list(lista2)
    lista.sort()
    return lista


x = 1
lista = []
while x > 0:
    x  = int(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))
    lista.append(x)
del lista[-1]

remove_repetidos()
```

Comment: Faltou passar a lista como parâmetro em remove_repetidos()

Comment: acho q estou com dificuldades nessa questão mesmo, como faço isso?

Comment: basta fazer `remove_repetidos(lista)` ali na ultima linha

Comment: fiz isso e deu outro erro agora, remove_repetidos() take 0 positional argumentos, but 1 was given

Comment: Qual erro? Aqui quando eu copiei e colei deu erro também. No meu caso era só por conta do acento em "número". Depois disso, funcionou normalmente como esperado. Veja se de repente é isso aí também.

Comment: Eu resolvi colocando lista entre os parênteses da função lá no começo do código, e no final também quando chama a função, seria isto mesmo? Existe alguma maneira de colocar o parâmetro apenas na chamada da função? Exemplo, se eu estivesse trabalhando com duas listas e quiser usar a mesma função para organizá-las

Answer (score 2):

Primeira, Python é uma liguagem Interpretada não compilada, [se quiser saber mais click aqui!](https://henriquebastos.net/diferencas-entre-linguagem-compilada-e-linguagem-interpretada/)

Como sua declaração da função **remove_repetidos (lista)** pede um parâmetro você deve passa-lo. 
no caso de listas o python não cria uma cópia da lista e sim passa um ponteiro da mesma.

Tente isso.

```
def remove_repetidos (lista):
    lista2 = set(lista)
    lista = list(lista2)
    lista.sort()
    return lista

def main():
   x = 1
   lista = []
   while x > 0:
       x  = int(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))
       lista.append(x)
   del lista[-1]

   remove_repetidos(lista)

main()
```

Comment: Neste caso, a cópia da lista está sendo feita na conversão para `set` e para `list` novamente, então `lista` que é retornado será diferente da `lista` de entrada, o que exige você utilizar o retorno da função.

Answer (score 0):

O erro diz que você chamou a função `remove_repetidos`, que espera um argumento, sem argumentos. Para arrumar isso, basta informá-lo devidamente. Porém, a nova lista será **retornada** pela função, então você precisa capturar este retorno.

Ficaria assim:

```
def remove_repetidos (lista):
    lista2 = set(lista)
    lista = list(lista2)
    lista.sort()
    return lista


x = 1
lista = []
while x > 0:
    x  = int(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))
    lista.append(x)
del lista[-1]

lista = remove_repetidos(lista)
#  ^                       ^                       
#  |                       +--- Passa o parâmetro para a função
#  +--- Captura o retorno da função

print(lista)  # Exibe a lista final
```

Outra forma de ler a lista seria:

```
lista = []

while True:
    x = int(input('Numero: '))
    if x == 0:
        break
    lista.append(x)
```

O que evita você de ter que inicializar o `x` igual a 1, elimina a condição **errada** `x > 0` do laço (pois a entrada pode ser negativa) e evita ter que excluir o último elemento, 0, da lista, adicionado indevidamente.

Faça o teste com a entrada `-5 -6 -2 -2 -3 0` com as duas soluções e compare os resultados.

Comment: Obrigado, realmente ficou melhor dessa forma, mas infelizmente tirei nota zero no meu teste, não o que está havendo pois meu programa está dando resultado como esperado. Segue o enunciado :Exercício 1 - Removendo elementos repetidos

Escreva a função remove_repetidos que recebe como parâmetro uma lista com números inteiros, verifica se tal lista possui elementos repetidos e os remove. A função deve devolver uma lista correspondente à primeira lista, sem elementos repetidos. A lista devolvida deve estar ordenada.

Dica: Você pode usar lista.sort() ou sorted(lista). Qual a diferença?