# Script que recebe uma lista de números inteiros, ordena e retira duplicados

Tags: python, python-3.x

estou fazendo curso de `python` e estou tentando resolver o seguinte exercício:

Exercício 1 - Removendo elementos repetidos

Escreva a função remove_repetidos que recebe como parâmetro uma lista com números inteiros, verifica se tal lista possui elementos repetidos e os remove. A função deve devolver uma lista correspondente à primeira lista, sem elementos repetidos. A lista devolvida deve estar ordenada.

Dica: Você pode usar `lista.sort()` ou `sorted(lista)`. Qual a diferença?

Postei meu código e tirei nota zero, não estou entendendo onde estou errando. Segue:

```
def remove_repetidos (lista):
    lista2 = set(lista)
    lista = list(lista2)
    lista.sort()
    print (lista)


lista = []

while True:
    x = int(input('Numero: '))
    if x == 0:
        break
    lista.append(x)

remove_repetidos(lista)
```

Comment: Dica: veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) como formatar o código nas postagens, e clique em [edit] para fazê-lo na sua pergunta.

Comment: obrigado amigo, já salvei aqui

Comment: No enunciado ele dá exemplos de como devem ser a entrada e a saída?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Chamar lista em função no python 3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/310795/chamar-lista-em-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-python-3)

Comment: Você não está fazendo nada com o resultado da função `remove_repetidos`. Você não falou qual o site em que está fazendo o exercício, mas talvez tenha que printar o resultado ou definir uma função específica para que ele reconheça as respostas. Leia as instruções.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seja autoexplicativo, a função `set()` remove os duplicados e a função `sorted()` ordena [lexicográficamente](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordem_lexicogr%C3%A1fica) um iterável:

```
def remove_repetidos(lista):
  return sorted(set(lista))
```

Comment: Você matou a charada, com um código de duas linhas kkkk obrigado, passei no teste. Mais um aprendizado!

Comment: Se a resposta lhe serviu, por favor marque a como correta, assim voce ajuda outros com o mesmo problema.

Comment: sou novo aqui amigo, ainda não me adaptei a esse site, acho que marquei como correta, caso eu tenha feito errado me avise